# Accessing SKProductResponse from outside of object

Tags: ios, properties, in-app-purchase

I'm integrating In App Purchase into my app and have created an object that implements the delegate callback:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    // populate UI
    [request autorelease];
}
```

as one of its methods.

In my case I have multiple SKProduct objects that will be returned by response.products. What I'd like to do is be able to access the myProduct array outside of the object in a view controller where I reflect some of the SKProduct details like price and product description.

Here's the interface declaration for the In App Purchase class:

```
@interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver> {

    NSArray *myProducts;
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;

}

// public methods
- (void)loadStore;
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases;
- (void)purchaseFeature:(NSString *)productId;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myProducts;

@end
```

Then the viewDidLoad method in my view controller:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
        /* Instantiate InAppPurchaseManager object then kick it off to collect Product info */
    iapManager = [InAppPurchaseManager new];
    [iapManager loadStore];

    SKProduct *myProduct;

    for (myProduct in iapManager.myProducts) {
            NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , myProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , myProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , myProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , myProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

} // end viewDidLoad
```

I get an exception:

> [InAppPurchaseManager myProducts]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x162d60

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I "export" my SKProduct data to my view controller? Any ideas are much appreciated!

Also, in the productsRequest: method, I'm able to use NSLog and print through the same loop and see the SKProduct data beautifully reflected in the console output; it just doesn't work in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: did you synthesize the myProducts property?

Comment: No I didn't do that. But if I do it like so: @synthesize myProducts; I'm still not able to see any data in the myProducts variable within the viewDidLoad method, or the view controller more broadly.

Answer (score 1):

OK. So there were a number of things I was missing. Thanks to Carl for getting me pointed in the right direction:

1) I was missing synthesize statements for myProducts in both the InAppPurchaseManager.m file and the ViewController.m file.
2) I needed @property statements for myProducts in the ViewController.h file.
3) I needed to set the myProducts property using self in the productsRequest method of the InAppPurchaseManager.m file:

```
self.myProducts = response.products;
```

This is why the data held in myProducts was never visible in the ViewController.

Hope this helps somebody else out there!